# EditText in android wear/How to input text in android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm building an android wear app that needs to take in text input. I've tried using `EditText`, and it shows up fine, but when I click the textBox, no keyboard pops up. How do I get text or voice input in android wear?

EDIT: here is the code for the editText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/titleTV"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/titleTV"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:editable="true" />
```

Comment: Add the code you have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there is no IME on a wear device, you have a few options to capture user's input:

- If you are working with Notifications, then there is a [way](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/voice-input.html) to build a notification that can take a voice reply on a watch.
- If you can, provide a set of canned responses/choices for the user to select from a list
- If you want a more free-form input, use [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) to capture user's voice input as a text.